# Determine what Fragment is shown

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Im trying to figure out how to determine what fragment is shown. I unfourantly cannot figure out how to start going about writing this code. Here is my source below.

### Fragment

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {
    WebView web;
    static ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup grp, Bundle icicle) {
        View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, grp, false);
        web = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        web.setWebViewClient(new SpecialWebView(progressBar));
        web.setWebChromeClient(new SpecialWebChromeClient(progressBar));
        // Progress Bar - End

        WebSettings websettings = web.getSettings();
        websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        web.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f2"));
        websettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        websettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        websettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        websettings.setSavePassword(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater Inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        Inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {
        final int current = ((ViewPager) mFragments).getCurrentItem();
        String currentId = current == 0 ? FRAGMENT1: (current == 1 ? FRAGMENT2: FRAGMENT3);
        //WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(currentId);
        switch (Item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_back:
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_forward:
            web.goForward();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            web.reload();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(Item);
    }
```

### MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private ViewPager mPager;
private TitlePageIndicator mIndicator;
private MainPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private List<Fragment> mFragments;

private static final String FRAGMENT1 = Fragment1.class.getName();
private static final String FRAGMENT2 = Fragment2.class.getName();
private static final String FRAGMENT3 = SupportFragment.class.getName();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_main);

    // add fragments
    mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FRAGMENT1));
    mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FRAGMENT2));
    mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FRAGMENT3));

    // adapter
    mAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments);

    // pager
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // indicator
    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.title_indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what adapter you're subclassing, but why not override the `getView()` callback to set a class variable for your activity? Then you could just check the value of the variable every time you want know which fragment is showing.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    MainActivity.setCurrentlyShownFragment(position);
    return SomeFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

That's the easiest way that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out whether a `Fragment` is shown isn't that hard. In your `Fragment` code just override `setUserVisibleHint()`. This takes a boolean that is true if the fragment UI is visible and false if it is not.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
if (isVisibleToUser) { 
   //Do something
} else {  
   //Do something else
}

}
```

You then just include what you want to do in the visible case and non-visible case within the appropriate parts of the conditional statment. Depending on what you're trying to do this may involve using an `Interface` to pass data to the containing fragment activity so you can reach other fragments or perform certain activity based functions.

Comment: Will this work for determining which out of the 3 fragments is shown in my viewpager?

Comment: Yup. I've used it in a 3 fragment `ViewPager` set up myself. In my set up I used an interface to call back to the adapter activity that contained the actual viewpager. That way I could tell the adapter which fragment was visible and perform different tasks accordingly.